# Understanding Calling Variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to understand what's happening here in this short little snippet, but I'm not well versed in Ruby. Ultimately, what I'm trying to figure out is what's the difference between .path and [:path]?

```
if(hit.props && hit.props.path)
      original_path = hit.props[:path]
```

I understand the if-statement part. Check if hit has props, and if it does check to see if it also has path in the props. I'm just confused as to what [:path] is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's the difference between .path and [:path]

`.path` is a method call. `:path` creates a [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html).

---

`hit.props.path` calls the `props` method on the `hit` object. Then calls `.path` on whatever is returned from that. It's equivalent to:

```
tmp = hit.props
tmp.path
```

---

`hit.props[:path]` again calls the `props` method on the `hit` object. Then fetches the value from that (which is probably a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html)) the `:path` key. `:path` is a Symbol which is kind of like a read-only shared String. They're often used as hash keys to save a bit of memory and to make things look a bit neater.

It's equivalent to:

```
tmp = hit.props
val = tmp[:path]
```

While I said Symbols are similar to Strings, they are not Strings. `tmp[:path]` and `tmp["path"]` are not equivalent.

---

What your code is doing is checking that `hit.props` and `hit.props.path` exist before trying `hit.props[:path]`. This is probably incorrect; `hit.props.path` is not used.

You probably only want to check for `hit.props` before trying to use it as a Hash.

```
if hit.props
  original_path = hit.props[:path]
```

This can be further reduced using the [Safe Navigation Operator `&.`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) introduced in Ruby 2.3.

```
original_path = hit.props&.[](:path)
```

It works just like a normal method call, but if the object is `nil` the call will return `nil` rather than an error. If `hit.props` is `nil` then `original_path` will be `nil`. It DRYs up your code and eliminates redundant method calls; `hit.props` is only called once.

Note that we're taking advantage of the fact that `props[:path]` is really syntax sugar for calling the method `[]` on the `props` object. A bit mind-bending, but all that's happening is it's [a method with a weird name](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Anybody know why Ruby doesn't permit `hit.props&[:path]` as sugar?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It would be a sweet feature, but that already means `hit.props.&([:path])`. For example [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-26). `arr = [:foo, :bar, :path]; arr&[:path];`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I can scratch that off my list.